# JSON document inserted as binary object in Couchbase

Tags: json, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I'm trying to insert a java POJO into the couchbase store and the json just below the `cas` call looks like this -

```
{
"key": "sampleKey",
"myMap": {
    "Messages": [
        {
            "field": "f1",
            "label": "l1"
        },
        {
            "field": "f2",
            "label": "l2"
        },
        {
            "field": "f3",
            "label": "l3"
        },
        {
            "field": "f4",
            "label": "l4"
        }
    ],
    "Orders": [
        {
            "field": "f1",
            "label": "l1"
        },
        {
            "field": "f2",
            "label": "l2"
        },
        {
            "field": "f3",
            "label": "l3"
        },
        {
            "field": "f4",
            "label": "l4"
        },
        {
            "field": "f5",
            "label": "l5"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have verified that this is a valid JSON and it's still being inserted as binary object as I try to look up this document via couchbase GUI, it shows up the base64 encoded string. A couple of other documents are fine though. I am wondering if this is happening only for the `cas` method and not `set`.

The relevant java code is this:

```
String myJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(cacheObject);
CASResponse response = couchbaseClient.cas(cacheObject.getKey(), casValue.getCas(), myJson, PersistTo.MASTER);

// Java pojo
public class CacheObject
{
    private String key;
    private Map<String, List<FieldLabel>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<FieldLabel>>();

    // setters and getters
}
```

Any pointers on why this could be happening will be appreciated.

Update1: I'm using Couchbase java client version 1.4.4, server's 2.5

Update2: I don't think this has to do with my code or json, I tried replacing my json with a large json document (a valid one) and I saw the same result in the couchbase GUI. I think this's happening because size of the document may go over 2.5KB. The json I pasted above has the actual field and labels removed, they are slightly longer strings.
Strangely, when I modify my document, documents below 960 characters generally show up as Json, however slightly above ones are stored as binary.

Comment: Can you please add your code and which version of the SDK you are using to your post? Having the JSON does not help as much as the java code.

Comment: @Kirk Added the details in the question.

Comment: In the Administration Console, json documents over a certain size show up as base64 encoded blobs. Can you get the document with the Java SDK to verify that json is returned to you?

Comment: @mikewied Shouldn't the message be something else in that case? The message I see on GUI is "Editing of binary objects is not allowed".

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the document is above 2.5KB the document will not be editable in console and this value can be changed in a file called documents.js